# How to Improve prediction accuracy using autoencoder to select features and SVM for training

Tags: classification, neural-networks, svm, autoencoders

I am using Matlab based implementation of autoencoder to compress my feature set (i have 2 cases, here i will talk about the one with 12 features). My goal is to predict human's opinion about a certain place. I have three choices i.e. -1, 0 and 1, each representing Dislike, Neither Like or dislike and Like respectively. I am using neural network based autoencoder to learn the compressed representation of my feature set. And then use these compressed features to train SVM with 70/30% split for prediction. I have labelled data, so I am doing supervised learning. Until now I am unable to achieve reasonable accuracy, so far accuracy is `~60%`. The data itself is tricky, for instance see below for a 2D scatter plot of the data. For this plot, i changed my autoencoder to have 2 features only, you can see the overlap (Color represents different classes - and i have three classes). So, my first question is that: can i use some other ML algorithm for both feature compression and supervised learning? 
[image]

My next question is that if the implementation of autoencoder is correct. I am using example from Matlab 2015a. Here is a chunk:

```
% Start autoencoding stuff
autoenc1 = feedforwardnet(hiddenSize1);
autoenc1.trainFcn = trainfunc;%'trainbr'%'trainlm';
autoenc1.trainParam.epochs = iH1;
autoenc1 = train(autoenc1,xTrain,xTrain);
% Create an empty network
autoencHid1 = network;

% Set the number of inputs and layers
autoencHid1.numInputs = 1;
autoencHid1.numlayers = 1;

% Connect the 1st (and only) layer to the 1st input, and also connect the
% 1st layer to the output
autoencHid1.inputConnect(1,1) = 1;
autoencHid1.outputConnect = 1;

% Add a connection for a bias term to the first layer
autoencHid1.biasConnect = 1;

% Set the size of the input and the 1st layer
autoencHid1.inputs{1}.size = iSize;
autoencHid1.layers{1}.size = hiddenSize1;

% Copy the weights and biases from the first layer of the trained
% autoencoder to this network
autoencHid1.IW{1,1} = autoenc1.IW{1,1};
autoencHid1.b{1,1} = autoenc1.b{1,1};

feat1 = autoencHid1(xTrain); % I will use these features to train SVM, also extending the same idea for next autoencoder layer
```

Is this sample looks ok, i am not hoping to use sparse autoencoders.

Comment: For checking the code, I'd rather monitor the reconstruction error, the activation of units and the visualization of weights on an image dataset like MNIST. I have the same question regarding feeding the features of autoencoder to an SVM. I didn't get good classification results either, the the other items mentioned above were reasonably correct.

Comment: Thanks! that's what I found as well, other limitation was fairly small dataset.